# Перекрестное подключение заголовков

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++, наследование

Доброго времени суток. Прошу помощи в следующем вопросе.

Имеется следующая архитектура проекта:

***file:*** baseobject.h

```
#pragma once
#include "modification\modification.h"

class Vetex;
class Modification;

class BaseObject 
{
public:
 virtual void modificate(Modification*, Vertex*) = 0;
}
```

***file:*** vertex.h

```
#pragma once
#include "baseobject.h"

class Vertex: public BaseObject
{
public:
 virtual void modificate(Modification*, Vertex*) override;
}
```

***file:*** normal.h
*(дополнительное наследование от класса GVertex - на всякий случай привожу, но думаю, что оно тут ни на что не влияет)*

```
#pragma once
#include "baseobject.h"

class Normal: public GVector, public BaseObject
{
public:
 virtual void modificate(Modification*, Vertex*) override;
}
```

***file:*** model.h

```
#pragma once
#include "normal.h"
#include "vertex.h"

class Model: public BaseObject
{
public:
 Normal* N;
 Vertex* V;
 virtual void modificate(Modification*, Vertex*) override;
}
```

***file:*** modification.h

```
#pragma once
#include "normal.h"
#include "vertex.h"

class Normal;
class Vertex;

class Modification
{
public:
 virtual void run(Vertex*) = 0;
 virtual void run(Normal*) = 0;
}
```

При включениях как у меня, происходят ошибки компиляции, что не определен базовый класс BaseObject в файлах vertex.h и normal.h. Дальше, что тип Modification не определен (в тех же файлах) итд с кучей ошибок подобного рода.
Возможно ли при такой архитектуре сделать так, чтобы скомпилировалось, или необходимо производить рефакторинг? :/
П.с. Если убрать один из классов (Вершина или Нормаль), то все будет компилироваться без ошибок.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну все верно. Смотрите - `vertex.h` включает сначала `baseobject.h`. Первое, что он делает - включает `modifications.h`. Тот - `normal.h`. Этот пропускает `baseobject.h` (он уже был), и первое, что он видит - видит что?

```
class Normal: public GVector, public BaseObject
{
public:
 virtual void modificate(Modification*, Vertex*) override;
}
```

И что такое `BaseObject`? Неизвестно...

Распутывайте свои классы. Вы же фактически зациклили включаемые заголовки...
Например - зачем в `baseobjects.h` включается `modifications.h`? Он же ничего, кроме неприятностей, не вносит. Уберите его оттуда.

Answer (score 0):

У вас так званный цикл зависимостей. Для того, чтобы его исправить, можно сказать компилятору что будет класс BaseObject, но потом. Это называеться forward-declaration.

Для того, чтобы его применить, добавьте это над определениями классов:

```
class BaseObject;
class Normal: public GVector, public BaseObject
```

Единственная проблема, то что вы не можете в header-ре обращаться к переменным и ф-циям класса BaseObject из-за того, что они еще не определенны. Но мы можете к ним обращаться из вашего .cpp файла.